# WPF TreeView not loading TreeViewItems until the parent is expanded

Tags: wpf, treeview

I'm experiencing an issue with a Treeview that is driving me crazy!!!

My TreeView is databound to an object model that is 3 levels deep, and uses a HierarchicalDataTemplate to define what should be displayed for each level:

Company
+-Branch
--+--Contact

I want to make a specific contact the selected node, which I'm doing like this (contact is the object from the databound object model):

```
Dim companyTreeViewItem As TreeViewItem = Me.AgentTreeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(contact.Branch.Company)
Dim branchTreeViewItem As TreeViewItem = companyTreeViewItem.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(contact.Branch)
Dim contactTreeViewItem As TreeViewItem = branchTreeViewItem.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(contact)
```

If I expand the treeview so the node that is going to be selected is visible (and then go and select something else) this code works, however if I run it before I expand any nodes branchTreeViewItem comes back as Nothing (null).

Any ideas how I can get to the TreeViewItem for my contact object and set it as selected?

**EDIT**

The code that populates the treeview is just setting the DataContext of the control:

```
Me.DataContext = New ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of DAL.Company)(From c In entities.Companies.Include("Branches").Include("Branches.Contacts") Order By c.CompanyName)
```

The treeview then has a simple binding

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" >
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the code that populates the TreeView?

Comment: @louisgab, I've updated the post to include the code that is populating the TreeView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper solution would be to use MVVM and create a view model for each item in the `TreeView` with `IsSelected` and `IsExpanded` properties bound to the corresponding `TreeViewItem` properties. Then you will be able to manipulate the `IsExpanded` and `IsSelected` states without having to dial with item containers generators.

But also you could do the following (sorry, my code will be in C#):

```
TreeViewItem companyTreeViewItem = (TreeViewItem)AgentTreeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(contact.Branch.Company);
companyTreeViewItem.IsExpanded = true;

companyTreeViewItem.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += (o, e) => {
    if (companyTreeViewItem.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated) 
    {
        TreeViewItem branchTreeViewItem = (TreeViewItem) companyTreeViewItem.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(contact.Branch);
        branchTreeViewItem.IsExpanded = true;

        branchTreeViewItem.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += (o1, e1) => {
            if (branchTreeViewItem.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated) 
            {
                TreeViewItem contactTreeViewItem = (TreeViewItem) branchTreeViewItem.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(contact);
                contactTreeViewItem.IsSelected = true;
            }
        };
    }
};
```